# Add class to navbar item when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I working on create one page website so what I need that for example if the section2 is appear in viewport add class active to link with href = "section2".

**Example** for what I need [one page website](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/orka-portfolio-one-page/full_screen_preview/19437245)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".links a").click(function (e) {
        if (this.getAttribute("href").charAt(0) == "#") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            $("html, body").stop();
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
            }, 1400)
        }
        else {
            $($(this)).attr("target", "_blank")
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.links{
  width:600px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  padding:20px;
}
.links a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border:1px solid #02e62a;
  color:#02e62a;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.links a:hover, .links a.active{
    color:#fe0101;
    border-color:#fe0101;
}
.section{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:300px auto 600px;
  background-color:#0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
        <a href="#home">Section 1</a>
        <a href="#about">Section 2</a>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">External Link</a>
        <a href="#services">Section 3</a>
        <a href="#contact">Section 4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="home" class="section"></div>
    <div id="about" class="section"></div>
    <div id="services" class="section"></div>
    <div id="contact" class="section"></div>
```

**Note:** please don't recommended me to use any plugin.

Comment: sidenote : your external link is wrong :)

Comment: why it's wrong :)

Comment: when you say "when section2 appears to viewport" do you mean when something is added to it dynamically through javascript ? because `section2` is a div , an empty div, it already appears and its appearance is nothing :)

Comment: it's `http://www.google.com`, you forgot `www`

Comment: :) :) it's just for test it's also work thank you for your note

Comment: @niceman why is `www` necessary?

Comment: yea why it's necessary?

Comment: @Turnip didn't work with my browser !! :/

Comment: such a "niceman" you are :)

Comment: @MichaelNeas [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491068/sticky-navigation-bar-with-scroll-effect-doesnt-work-on-browser-while-it-does-o) might help you with your problem

Comment: @HassanZia it does work without `www` but not through `Run Snippet` , hmmmm

Comment: @HassanZia I discovered I was affected by this question : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325572/why-does-target-blank-break-links-in-snippets/325573#325573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I think it provides you with the solution you want.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $('div[id^="section"]').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#" + id)) {
       $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    }
  })
})
```

**Note** it seems to bug a bit when you use it here with mouse scroll, so test it by pulling the scroll bar at the right. Dont know why, but im trying to solve it now.

**Update** the problem seems to be that snippet window is so small, if you run the example in `full page`, then it work just fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".links a").click(function(e) {
    if (this.getAttribute("href").charAt(0) == "#") {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
      $("html, body").stop();
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
      }, 1400)
    } else {
      $($(this)).attr("target", "_blank")
    }
  })
})

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $('div.section').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#" + id)) {
      $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    }
  })
})

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

```css
.links {
  width: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #02e62a;
  color: #02e62a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.links a:hover,
.links a.active {
  color: #fe0101;
  border-color: #fe0101;
}

.section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 300px auto 600px;
  background-color: #0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#Home">Home</a>
  <a href="#About">About</a>
  <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">External Link</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#Blog">Blog</a>
</div>
<div id="Home" class="section"></div>
<div id="About" class="section"></div>
<div id="Contact" class="section"></div>
<div id="Blog" class="section"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but please could you explain me the code :)

Comment: It works fine when i enter the snippet editor, so try it out in your own code, and then it might work as it should do. I'll try solve the problem right away

Comment: @MichaelNeas Check my update statement, hit "Run code snippet" then click on "Full page" in the right top cornor, it should work just find

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: but if the section one is called home and section 2 is called about this will occur problem!!

Comment: I Will Edit my Code and you will understand what I mean :)

Comment: Try look at mine now

Comment: Just look at the snippet, it should be fine and you should be able to mark the question as solved